# VSCode, WSL & Docker - Debugging with gdbserver

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote, gdbserver

I want to debug a C++ application with VSCode, running in docker container, inside WSL.

#### My current setup:

- VSCode is running on the host Windows machine. 'Native Debug' extension installed on the remote (should be installed locally?)
- Source code is within WSL Ubuntu distribution, VScode connected with WSL-Remote.
- The application can be executed from a docker container, with gdbserver installed. Container is with fixed IP (172.17.0.2).

I already ran gdbserver on the container with:

`gdbserver 172.17.0.2:9999 /path/to/app`

How can I attach VScode to the gdbserver, running in a container on the WSL?

Here is what I've already tried, and the outcome:

1. ```
        {
            "name": "Simple Native Plugin",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "attach",
            "executable": "./app",
            "target": "172.17.0.2:9999",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remote": true
        },
   ```

Result:

```
Could not start debugger process, does the program exist in filesystem?
Error: spawn gdb ENOENT
```

2. ```
     {
         "name": "(gdb) Attach - WSL - Native Plugin",
         "type": "gdb",
         "request": "attach",
         "target" : "172.17.0.2:9999",
         "remote" : true,
         "executable": "${workspaceFolder}/app",
         "gdbpath": "/usr/bin/gdbserver",
         "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",

     },
   ```

Result:

```
undefined/bin/bash: line 0: exec: -q: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
During startup program exited with code 2.
Exiting
```

3. ```
    {
         "name": "(gdb) Launch - WSL - CPPdbg Plugin",
         "type": "cppdbg",
         "request": "launch",
         "remote" : true,
         "miDebuggerServerAddress": "172.17.0.2:9999",
         "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdbserver",
         "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app",
         "args": [],
         "stopAtEntry": false,
         "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
         "externalConsole": true,
         "linux": {
             "MIMode": "gdb",
         },
         "windows": {
             "MIMode": "gdb"
         }
     }
   ```

Result:

```
Starting: "/usr/bin/gdbserver" --interpreter=mi
Unknown argument: --interpreter=mi
"/usr/bin/gdbserver" exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second try was almost correct. Try to enter the path to `gdb` instead of `gdbserver` in `gdbpath`.

Comment: Tried that. Got just the same as the first try:
`Could not start debugger process, does the program exist in filesystem?
Error: spawn /usr/bin/gdb ENOENT`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the TCP parameter for gdbserver is `host:port` where `host` is the IP of the host machine. The IP in the question is 172.17.0.2, which Docker uses for the Container's IP, try 172.17.0.1. That's the default for the host.

You can verify what addresses your container is using by running this in the host:

`docker container inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <image-name>`